# Build a map with Husky, laser and Kinect/RealSense

Tags: slam, navigation, realsense, realsense-camera, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm trying to build a 3D map with my mobile robot (Husky A200) by using a LMS-111 SICK laser and a RealSense R200 (which is a camera sensor like the Kinect).
Typically, I move my robot by using a remote transmitter along a specific path.

I'm able to build a 2D map in RVIZ by using the data coming from the **/scan** topic by using **hector_map** and this works very well since I don't need to use the odometry data.

I'm also able to build a 3D map in **rtabmap** by using only the **/camera/color/image_raw**, **/camera/depth/image_raw** and **/camera/color** topics coming from the RealSense sensor; also this method works very well and the map is very accurate.

Both with the RealSense and with the SICK, I can display the visual odometry and the laser odometry.

Now, I would like to know if it is possible to fuse both RealSense and SICK laser in a single map in order to match the data and check if the computed odometry is the same and to integrate the 2d data from the laser inside the 3D map built by using the camera sensor.

Do you think it is possible to achieve this?
Do I have to use gmapping?

If needed, I can also record /imu/data coming from my XSENS IMU, encoders and velocity data and also the husky odometry data.

I hope you can help me.
If you want I can upload some short bag files.

---

**EDIT:**
after **matlabbe** suggestion, I'm trying to use **RTABMAP** with ***subscribe_scan*** enabled, but I think I need help to specify the correct transformation between the **laser frame** and the **base_link** since I'm getting this error:

```
rtabmapviz: Could not get transform from base_link to laser after 0.100000 seconds!
```

In order to start the RTABMAP, I use the following commands:

```
$ roscore
$ rosparam set use_sim_time true
$ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 -1.5707963 0 -1.5707963 base_link camera_color_optical_frame 100
$ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 camera_color_optical_frame camera_depth_optical_frame 100
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rgbd_mapping.launch rgb_topic:=/camera/color/image_raw depth_registered_topic:=/camera/depth/image_raw camera_info_topic:=/camera/color/camera_info compressed:=true frame_id:=base_link rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" estimation:=1
$ rosbag play --clocktest1.bag (the bag contains both realsense and laser data)
```

At the end of rgbd_mapping.launch, I added this code:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"  name="base_to_realsense"
      args="0 0 0 -1.5707963 0 -1.5707963 /base_link /realsense_frame 100" />
```

And this works well if I only use the RealSense data, but if I enable the scan data, it gives me the transformation error since I dont know how to correctly define it. Can you help me, please?

*The SICK laser is located 50 centimeters lower than the RealSense and it is mounted on the same vertical axis.*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239646/build-a-map-with-husky,-laser-and-kinect/realsense/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-07-16**:
Is it possible to build a 3d with gmapping?

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-07-16**:
What I want to acquire is to mix the 3d map with the 2d map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'll try to breakdown some solutions that you can explore. I assume your laser is mounted horizontally and that you are on a 2D terrain.

1. [hector_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping) provides **icp odometry** and a **2D occupancy grid map**, but it doesn't do loop closure detection/correction (*someone correct me if I am wrong*).
2. [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) provides a **2D occupancy grid map** with **loop closure detection/correction**, but requires odometry as input. You could take icp odometry from hector_mapping to use it.
3. [rtabmap_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) provides **3D point cloud map** and **2D occupancy grid map** (see `subscribe_scan` option) with **loop closure detection/correction**. It requires odometry as input but a **visual odometry** node is provided for convenience. You could also use icp odometry from hector_mapping instead. See [SetupOnYourRobot](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot) tutorial to see some configurations.

Well, solution 3 can provide what you want. For odometry, if you want to mix visual odometry and/or icp odometry and/or IMU together (sensor fusion), you may want to look at the [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) package.

**EDIT 1: TF problem**

You need a `static_transform_publisher` between `/base_link` and `/laser` frames. Not sure if I understand the relation between `/camera_color_optical_frame` and `/realsense_frame`. What is the `frame_id` set in your `/camera/color/image_raw` topic? Assuming it is `/camera_color_optical_frame`, the laser is 10 cm over `/base_link` and RGB camera is on your vertical axis 50 cm over the laser:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"  name="base_to_laser"
      args="0 0 0.1 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 100" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"  name="base_to_color"
      args="0 0 0.6 -1.5707963 0 -1.5707963 /base_link /camera_color_optical_frame 100" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"  name="color_to_depth"
      args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /camera_color_optical_frame /camera_depth_optical_frame 100" />
```

You would have:

```
/base_link -----> /laser
           \
             ---> /camera_color_optical_frame -> /camera_depth_optical_frame
```

**EDIT 2: Sensor fusion**

Use [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) and configure it to output TF `/odom` -> `/base_link` along with the fused odometry (`/odometry/filtered`). If you use [rgbd_odometry](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rgbd_odometry), you should set `publish_tf` param to false to avoid publishing the same odom TF. There is basic example (still need some modifications) in the launch file [sensor_fusion.launch](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/tests/sensor_fusion.launch) for IMU+Visual odometry. Please read the guidelines in [robot_localization's tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials) to better tune [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) parameters for your sensors.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-07-18**:
Thank you for your help. I think option 3 is suitable for me. I can get odometry data from my robot husky since it provides Odom node. How can I add the odometer data inside rtabmap? Is there any tutorial?

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-07-18**:
Do you think is it possible to include IMU data in rtabmap? Is there any documentation for this?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-07-18**:
I updated the answer above with a link to a tutorial with different configurations. You may want to look at the Kinect+Laser+Odom one. To merge IMU + husky odom into a fused odometry for rtabmap, see robot_localization package.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-07-18**:
I edited my first question by including the error I'm getting if I try to use RTABMAP with the scan enabled. I tried to read how to specify the transformation between the laser and the base_link, but I didn't came with any suitable solution. Can you help me please?

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-07-18**:
Thank you a lot, Matlabbe! It works very nice, now! You really are a ROS Master! I've read on 'SetupUpOnYourRobot' that I can use also my IMU (/imu/data) in order to perform sensor fusion (realsense+laser+imu). Do I have to use robot_localization or can I use only RTABMAP?

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-07-18**:
How can I include my /imu/data in order to make it looks like an odometry message?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-07-18**:
updated answer above...

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-07-19**:
Thank you! I marked the question as solved. I will open another topic related to robot_localization to avoid Off Topic here. Thank you again for your help!

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-07-19**:
I opened a new question on http://answers.ros.org/question/239823/build-a-map-with-rtabmap-realsense-sick-and-imu-with-sensor-fusion/ in order to continue the discussion on the IMU integration. I've read the robot_localization tutorials, but something is not very clear to me, unfortunately.